# Wordpress: Unable to retrieve post content in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have written something that will send me an email with the contents of a post once it is published. I am able to get the title, category, author and permalink from the post and show it in the mail, but not the content!

```
<?php

// Function that runs when a post is published
function run_when_post_published() {

    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
    $category = get_the_category();
    $author_id = $post->post_author;
    $author = get_the_author_meta( 'nickname', $author_id ); 
    $title = get_the_title();
    $permalink = get_permalink();
    $my_content = get_the_content();

    $email_subject = '(' . $category[0]->cat_name . ') Case fra kundelogg: ' . $title;
    $message = $my_content . 'Written by: ' . $author . ', Link: ' . $permalink;
    $headers = 'From: CRM System <mail@mail.com>';

// Advanced custom field to check if post is supposed to be mailed or not
if( !empty($_POST['fields']['field_52fc8615d3526'] ) ) {

    $email = 'myemail@mycompany.com';
    wp_mail( $email, $email_subject, $message );

}
else { // Do nothing }

}

// Makes sure email only gets sent the first time a post is published
add_action('new_to_publish', 'run_when_post_published');        
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'run_when_post_published');      
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'run_when_post_published');
?>
```

I have tried numerous ways of getting the content to show up in the mail, and in some cases i acctually got between two to six characters to show up. But not the whole content. It is like the content is truncated randomly, but this is not the case. The example in the code above with get_the_content() does not show anything though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace $my_content inside $message = ... with `apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content )`

```
$message = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ) . ' Written by: ' . $author . ', Link: ' . $permalink;
```

Remove `$post = get_post( $post_id );`

Add $post as a function argument.

In the final version below I have made the changes I listed above however I haven't made any attempt to cleanup your code. Here's the full version:

```
<?php

// Function that runs when a post is published
function run_when_post_published( $post ) {
    $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
    $category = get_the_category();
    $author_id = $post->post_author;
    $author = get_the_author_meta( 'nickname', $author_id ); 
    $title = get_the_title();
    $permalink = get_permalink();

    $email_subject = '(' . $category[0]->cat_name . ') Case fra kundelogg: ' . $title;
    $message = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ) . 'Written by: ' . $author . ', Link: ' . $permalink;
    $headers = 'From: CRM System <mail@mail.com>';

    // Advanced custom field to check if post is supposed to be mailed or not
    if( !empty($_POST['fields']['field_52fc8615d3526'] ) ) {

        $email = 'myemail@mycompany.com';
        wp_mail( $email, $email_subject, $message );

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, that worked! I have tried using it that way with apply_filters(...), but i must have done it very wrong! :) the problem i am left with, is showing the content as HTML. I tried using:

add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

but i only get this error message: (next comment)

Comment: Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'set_html_content_type' was given in /home/kundelog/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 199

Comment: You need to set the content type as html. Look in the docs for wp_mail

Comment: Did you define set_html_content_type as a function?

Comment: Setting it as a function solved it, Thanks! Found my answer here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_content_type